# XMLHttpRequest returns status of 0 in Firefox 3.6.10 and up from cross origin requests

Tags: firebug, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am developing an application that makes a cross origin AJAX request to an HTTP server written using Netty.

An example of the type of Javascript code being executed is below.

```
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"http://localhost:5000/someresource",
            data: { id1: "1", id2: "2" },
            success: function(status, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert("Success")
            },
            error: function(status, textStatus, xhr) {
                alert("Error")
            }
        });
```

The problem I am seeing is that on Firefox (3.6.10 and 4.0 beta) the status of the XMLHttpRequest is always 0, regardless of the status of the response. In firebug I can see that the server is returning the correct status for the request, but this is not being pushed through to the XMLHttpRequest object.

Below is the request and response headers being sent

> ```
> Response Headers
> Content-Type text/plain; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length 0
> Access-Control-Allow-Orig... http://localhost:9000
> Cache-Control no-cache
> Connection Keep-Alive
> Date Thu, 07 Oct 2010 07:52:08 GMT
>
> Request Headers
> Host localhost:5000
> User-Agent Mozilla/5.0.... 
> Accept */*
> Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
> Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
> Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
> Keep-Alive 115
> Connection keep-alive
> Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Referer http://localhost:9000/test
> Origin http://localhost:9000
> ```

I have tried executing the code in Chrome, Opera and Safari and they all work fine. Is this something I am doing or a bug in Firefox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this still an open issue?  I seem to be getting error behavior on Chrome 16 and Firefox 10.0 with regards to 302 redirects, XHR and CORS. Non-redirects work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem in both firefox 3.6+ and chrome.  The reason i found is that i was debugging the site on the localhost server.  Both of these will only return the appropriate response codes when it is ran from a remote url.  They both return different status codes for localhost.